# Splicing one array with another array values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, splice

I have a function `displaySelectedRole()` and I have variables `$scope.Role` and `$scope.rolenames` .I need to remove all values available in `$scope.role` from `$scope.rolename.`

```
$scope.role= ["A","B","C"]; 

$scope.rolename =["A","B","C","D","E"]
```

I need to splice the values and get `$scope.rolename = ["D","E"]`

```
$scope.displaySelectedRole = function(role, index) {
           debugger;
           $scope.role.splice(RoleNames[index]);
            console.log($scope.role);
```

I tried to use splice based on index , but problem is it given empty array values in console.

Comment: `$scope.rolename.filter(x=>!$scope.role.includes(x))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you [**Underscore.js's `difference()`**](http://underscorejs.org/#difference), it purposes a method to substract arrays:

```
$scope.role = ["A","B","C"]; 
$scope.rolename = ["A","B","C","D","E"];
$scope.diff = _.difference($scope.rolename, $scope.role); // ["D","E"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var $scope = {};  // Ignore this line
$scope.role= ["A","B","C"]; 
$scope.rolename = ["A","B","C","D","E"];

$scope.rolename = $scope.rolename.filter(function(role){
   return $scope.role.indexOf(role) === -1;
})

console.log($scope.rolename);
```

If you want to remove them directly you could iterate through the `$scope.role` and use splice

```js
   var $scope = {};  // Ignore this line
   $scope.role= ["A","B","C"]; 
   $scope.rolename = ["A","B","C","D","E"];

   $scope.role.forEach(function(role){
   var index = $scope.rolename.indexOf(role);
   if(index !== -1) $scope.rolename.splice(index, 1);
})

console.log($scope.rolename);
```

**Note:** `Array.filter` will return a new array, unlike `array.splice` which will modify original array.

#### Reference

- [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)